# Question on meaning of **integrity** in this text on CBSA officers in Canada

Tags: word-meaning, legalese

> ...They help to ensure your smooth arrival, protect the **integrity** of Canada's **custom**, immigration and agricultural **laws**. The most important item to have with you is your passport, along with the **customs** Declaration Card that you have filled out on a plane.

1. What the diffrence is between saying **agricultural laws** and **agricultural rules** ?
2. What does **integrity** here mean? **integrity** of Canada's custom
3. And the most difficulty I have here, are the both words **custom** mean the same ? St first I thought the first refers to tradition and the second refers to goods coming into a country. But know I think both of them is refering to goods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Laws are actual legislation enacted by the government. In this case these are all enacted at the Federal level and govern all of Canada. Rules are often included with regulations and accompany the law or regulations. In the case of the CBSA two of the many pieces of legislation - laws that are administered by them include the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act and the Regulations to it, as well as the Customs Act and Regulations. So Agricultural laws are what one must follow and failing to follow the law may result in penalties. The rules or regulations give the direction of how the law is to be followed. Both parts work together.
2. In this regard integrity means "the state of being whole, entire, or undiminished: such as - to preserve the integrity of the empire." see dictionary.com
3. Both of the words customs should be plural. The first would be read Canada's customs laws so those laws related to Canada customs (entry of goods and people to Canada). The second refers to the declaration card so is particular to goods upon which one may be required to pay tax or duty when entering Canada. Neither relates to the customs or cultural aspect of Canada.